# Multiple conditions and MySQLConnections issue in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, database-connection

I have a button click event that checks conditions within multiple input elements on a form. Textboxes, radio, combo buttons, etc.

In addition, the method check whether a text entry for username is unique or already existent in the database. If the user meets all conditions, than with the else statement is activated and the entries are stored in the database.

This is the method below:

```
    private void button2_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int Vid_Smetka;

        if (radioNewAdmin.Checked)
        {
            Vid_Smetka = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Vid_Smetka = 0;
        }


        if (txtNewUser.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Корисничкото име е празно. Ве молиме пополнете го полето.", "Потсетник", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else if (txtNewFullname.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ве молиме пополнете го полето за целосно име и презиме.", "Потсетник", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else if (txtNewEmail.Text == String.Empty || !txtNewEmail.Text.Contains('@'))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ве молиме пополнете го полето за email. Користете валидна e-mail адреса.", "Потсетник", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else if (txtNewPassword.Text.Length < 6)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ве молиме внесете најмалку 6 карактери во лозинката.", "Потсетник", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

        }
        else if (!txtNewPassword.Text.Any(x => char.IsUpper(x)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ве молиме внесете барем една голема буква во лозинката.", "Потсетник", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else if (!txtNewPassword.Text.Any(x => char.IsLower(x)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ве молиме внесете барем една мала буква во лозинката.", "Потсетник", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else if (txtNewPassword.Text != txtNewRepeatPassword.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Лозинките не се совпаѓаат. Ве молиме обидете се повторно.", "Потсетник", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

        }
        else if (!radioNewAdmin.Checked && !radioNewUser.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ве молиме селектирајте тип на сметка.", "Потсетник", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboNewFunction.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ве молиме функција на корисникот на сметката во училиштето.", "Потсетник", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

        }
        else if (txtNewUser.Text != String.Empty)
        {

            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["#.Properties.Settings.ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            conn.Open(); //Try to open the connection to the MySql database

            //Check if there is a row with credentials entered in the form
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT Count(*) FROM #.# WHERE Korisnik = '" + txtNewUser.Text + "'", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            //Initiate a new connection string

            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() != "0")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Корисничкото име е зафатено. Ве молиме обидете внесете уникатно.", "Потсетник", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
        else
        {

            var sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO #.#" +
            "(Korisnik, Lozinka, Vid_Smetka, email, user_function, full_name) " +
            "VALUES ('" + this.txtNewUser.Text + "', '" + this.txtNewPassword.Text + "', '" + Vid_Smetka + "', " +
            "'" + this.txtNewEmail.Text + "', '" + this.comboNewFunction.Text + "', '" + this.txtNewFullname.Text + "');";

            //Initiate a new connection string

            try
            {
                using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString))
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(sqlCommand, con);
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader myReader;
                    myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = loadData().Tables[0];

                    MessageBox.Show("Зачувано.", "Известување", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    panelNew.Visible = false;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)

            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        } 
    }
```

This is obviously quite simple. But, for a certain reason the else statement is not executing when all other conditions are met.

I am making a mistake with the MySQLConnection? Any hints where I might be getting it wrong?

Comment: You have a logic problem - your first `if` condition is `txtNewUser.Text == String.Empty`, while your final `else if` is `txtNewUser.Text != String.Empty` meaning it will always go into one of those two (or one of the others) and never drop into the final else.

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes you were right. I should've seen that. Thank you.

Comment: Google for "Bobby Tables". *Don't* create SQL statements by concatenating strings. Use parameterized queries. Apart from the *very* serious risk of SQL injection you'll run into conversion issues if you pass numbers or dates without using the *same* locale as the server, or if you pass non-ANSI characters without specifying the codepage

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes I am aware that I should use parameterized queries. I will definitely refactor the code. Just wanted to make it work first. Still quite new to C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this section runs:

```
else if (txtNewUser.Text != String.Empty)
    {

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["#.Properties.Settings.ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        conn.Open(); //Try to open the connection to the MySql database

        //Check if there is a row with credentials entered in the form
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT Count(*) FROM #.# WHERE Korisnik = '" + txtNewUser.Text + "'", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        //Initiate a new connection string

        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() != "0")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Корисничкото име е зафатено. Ве молиме обидете внесете уникатно.", "Потсетник", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
```

...then it will exit the overall `if` statement so this...

```
else
    {

        var sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO #.#" +
        "(Korisnik, Lozinka, Vid_Smetka, email, user_function, full_name) " +
        "VALUES ('" + this.txtNewUser.Text + "', '" + this.txtNewPassword.Text + "', '" + Vid_Smetka + "', " +
        "'" + this.txtNewEmail.Text + "', '" + this.comboNewFunction.Text + "', '" + this.txtNewFullname.Text + "');";

        //Initiate a new connection string

        try
        {
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

...will not run afterwards. If you want to run the `INSERT INTO` code after checking that the user name is unique, change the last part of your code to this:

```
else if (txtNewUser.Text != String.Empty)
    {

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["#.Properties.Settings.ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        conn.Open(); //Try to open the connection to the MySql database

        //Check if there is a row with credentials entered in the form
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT Count(*) FROM #.# WHERE Korisnik = '" + txtNewUser.Text + "'", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        //Initiate a new connection string

        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() != "0")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Корисничкото име е зафатено. Ве молиме обидете внесете уникатно.", "Потсетник", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            con.Close();

            var sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO #.#" +
                "(Korisnik, Lozinka, Vid_Smetka, email, user_function, full_name) " +
                "VALUES ('" + this.txtNewUser.Text + "', '" + this.txtNewPassword.Text + "', '" + Vid_Smetka + "', " +
                "'" + this.txtNewEmail.Text + "', '" + this.comboNewFunction.Text + "', '" + this.txtNewFullname.Text + "');";

            //Initiate a new connection string

            try
            {
                using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString))
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(sqlCommand, con);
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader myReader;
                    myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = loadData().Tables[0];

                    MessageBox.Show("Зачувано.", "Известување", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    panelNew.Visible = false;

                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```